# Deadlock wait resource RID

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

Can anyone help me with the steps to decode the exact culprit of the deadlock when wait resource is RID and also how to remove that deadlock?

Comment: That might depend on the database engine, which you failed to specify.

Comment: Hi I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

you can use Sp who & sp who2 System Stored Procedures

> sp_who
>
> Sp_who returns information about system and user activity.
>   Sp_who returns the following columns:   Spid  System process id that
>   requested the lock Ecid   Execution context of the thread associated
>   with the spid. Zero means the main thread, all other numbers mean
>   sub-threads.  Status  Runnable, sleeping, or background. If the status
>   is runnable that means the process is actually performing work,
>   sleeping means the process is connected to the server, but is idle at
>   the moment.  Loginname    The login that has initiated the lock request
>   Hostname  The name of the computer where the lock request was initiated
>   Blk   The connection that is blocking the lock request from the current
>   connection Dbname Database name where the lock has been requested
>   Cmd   General command type that requested the lock The syntax of sp_who
>   also allows specifying a single login, however, most of the time it
>   will be executed with no parameters. The output of sp_who is very
>   similar to the output of sp_who2.
>
> sp_who2
>
> Sp_who2 is a newer version of sp_who. It returns some
>   additional information:   Spid    System process id that requested the
>   lock Status   Background, sleeping or runnable Login  The login name that
>   has requested the lock HostName   The computer where the lock request
>   has been initiated BlkBy  The spid of the connection that is blocking
>   the current connection DbName The database name where the lock request
>   has been generated Command    General command type that requested the
>   lock CPUTime  The number of milliseconds the request has used
>   DiskIO    Disk input / output that the command has used LastBatch Date
>   and time of the last batch executed by the connection ProgramName The
>   name of the application that issued the connection Spid   In case you
>   can't read the spid from the beginning of the output it is repeated
>   here Example: Sp_who2

Blocking details :

```
--============================================ 
--View Blocking in Current Database 
--Author: Timothy Ford 
--http://thesqlagentman.com 
--============================================ 
SELECT DTL.resource_type,  
   CASE   
       WHEN DTL.resource_type IN ('DATABASE', 'FILE', 'METADATA') THEN DTL.resource_type  
       WHEN DTL.resource_type = 'OBJECT' THEN OBJECT_NAME(DTL.resource_associated_entity_id)  
       WHEN DTL.resource_type IN ('KEY', 'PAGE', 'RID') THEN   
           (  
           SELECT OBJECT_NAME([object_id])  
           FROM sys.partitions  
           WHERE sys.partitions.hobt_id =   
           DTL.resource_associated_entity_id  
           )  
       ELSE 'Unidentified'  
   END AS requested_object_name, DTL.request_mode, DTL.request_status,    
   DOWT.wait_duration_ms, DOWT.wait_type, DOWT.session_id AS [blocked_session_id],  
   sp_blocked.[loginame] AS [blocked_user], DEST_blocked.[text] AS [blocked_command], 
   DOWT.blocking_session_id, sp_blocking.[loginame] AS [blocking_user],  
   DEST_blocking.[text] AS [blocking_command], DOWT.resource_description     
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks DTL  
   INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks DOWT   
       ON DTL.lock_owner_address = DOWT.resource_address   
   INNER JOIN sys.sysprocesses sp_blocked  
       ON DOWT.[session_id] = sp_blocked.[spid] 
   INNER JOIN sys.sysprocesses sp_blocking  
       ON DOWT.[blocking_session_id] = sp_blocking.[spid] 
   CROSS APPLY sys.[dm_exec_sql_text](sp_blocked.[sql_handle]) AS DEST_blocked 
   CROSS APPLY sys.[dm_exec_sql_text](sp_blocking.[sql_handle]) AS DEST_blocking 
WHERE DTL.[resource_database_id] = DB_ID()
```

[sp-who-to-find-dead-locks-in-SQL-Server](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/862872/sp-who-to-find-dead-locks-in-SQL-Server)

[different-techniques-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2732/different-techniques-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server/)

[understanding-sql-server-blocking](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1978/understanding-sql-server-blocking/)

Comment: How do you know queryguy is using SQL Server?

Comment: Hi Jophy Job, I would like to know more specific details when "wait resource is RID"

Comment: @queryguy updated , check this link for more : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1978/understanding-sql-server-blocking/

Comment: Hi, just wanted to confirm one thing, is it possible to remove deadlock from the system due to few queries when Wait resource is either "RID" or "key" without changing those queries?